# Can I use Roslyn CTP in a shared hosting?

Tags: asp.net, roslyn

Im wondering if it is possible to use some cool features of Roslyn such as dynamic compilation  in an ASP.NET application hosted in a shared hosting. Is that possible?

Comment: You really want to check out the Roslyn CTP license here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/jj150688 for legal issues.

Comment: Too much blahblah for me as I'm outside USA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work just fine. You might want to check out [compilify.net](https://compilify.net/) and what they're doing, as it's powered by Roslyn.